# Need to Delete or hide rows showing blank. But have formulas in them

Tags: excel, vba

Having trouble coming up with a way to remove blank rows after my code runs. The code works great, it compares two sets of data together to show the differences and return the PK and its associated row.

I have tried multiple delete functions/VBA code but cant seem to find one that does what I want. The Code below delets empty rows, but not rows with formulas.

```
Public Sub DeleteAllEmptyRows()
    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim RowIndex As Integer
    Dim UsedRng As Range

    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRowIndex = UsedRng.Row - 1 + UsedRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For RowIndex = LastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountA(Rows(RowIndex)) = 0 Then
            Rows(RowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next RowIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Deleted unnecessary rows to provide formatted rows.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will delete all rows in the used range of the active sheet without display values, i.e. both rows that contain formulas where the display conditions are not met AND entirely blank rows:

```
Public Sub DeleteAllEmptyRows()

    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer, RowIndex As Integer
    Dim UsedRng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    LastRowIndex = UsedRng.Row - 1 + UsedRng.Rows.Count

    For RowIndex = LastRowIndex To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rows(RowIndex), "?*") = 0 Then
            Rows(RowIndex).Delete
        End If
    Next RowIndex

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```